# How to exit knitr on error but still generate the partial output

Tags: r, error-handling, knitr

I generate a standardized report using knitr. To document errors easier (the input data is not always what is expected), I need a log file amended with plus nice HTML formatting and figure embedding. A log file lists results until an error occurs, then ends.

The default of knitr, however, is to print the error message into the output and then continue with the next chunks. Alternatively, using `knitr::opts_chunk$set(error = FALSE)`, one can abort the whole process when an error occurs, creating no markdown output at all.

But I want knitr to print until reaching an error, then stop.
I can stop early and generate a HTML output using `knitr::knit_exit()`, but I cannot use it as an error handler. See the two examples below. The first does as expected, but the second one is supposed to output the error message "Test" as the last chunk. How can I achieve this?

### MWE 1: knit_exit()

````
knitr::knit(output = stdout(), text = "
```{r}
1 + 1
```

```{r}
knitr::knit_exit()
```

```{r}
2 + 2
```
")

## ```r
## 1 + 1
## ```
## 
## ```
## ## [1] 2
## ```
## 
## 
## ```r
## knitr::knit_exit()
## ```
````

### MWE 2: No error handling

````r
options(error = knitr::knit_exit); knitr::knit(output = stdout(), text = "
```{r}
1 + 1
```

```{r}
stop('Test')
``` 

This text should not be in the output.

```{r}
2 + 2
```
")



## ```r
## 1 + 1
## ```
## 
## ```
## ## [1] 2
## ```
## 
## 
## ```r
## stop('Test')
## ```
## 
## ```
## Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): Test
## ```
## 
## This text should not be in the output.
## 
## 
## ```r
## 2 + 2
## ```
## 
```
## [1] 4
```
````

Comment: can you use `try` or `trycatch`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct, it does not work to directly use `knitr::knit_exit()` as an error handler. However, you can override the error output hook with it to achieve your desired outcome:

````r
knitr::knit(
output = stdout(), 
text = "
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, error = TRUE)

# override error output hook here
knitr::knit_hooks$set(error = function(x, options) { 
  knitr::knit_exit()
})
```

```{r}
1 + 1
```

```{r}
stop('Test')
``` 

This text should not be in the output.

```{r}
2 + 2
```
")
```

    #> 
    #> 
    #> 
    #> 
    #> ```r
    #> 1 + 1
    #> #> [1] 2
    #> ```
    #> 
    #> 
    #> ```r
    #> stop('Test')
    #> ```
````

<sup>Created on 2022-10-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74186720/3082472) (which helped me a lot and you should upvote ;-) ) one might want the error message to be printed. In that case, the error hook can be used to signal knitr to quit but also save the error message, for example in a global variable. Then, the chunk hook can be used to print the error message in a last output block:

For that, use the following hooks

````
knitr::knit_hooks$set(error = function(x, options) {
  ERROR <<- x
  knitr::knit_exit()
})
knitr::knit_hooks$set(chunk = function(x, options){
  if(exists('ERROR')) paste0(x,'```\n',ERROR,'```\n\n**Skript stopped with error**')
  else x
})
````

Or, in the complete example:

````
knitr::knit(
    output = stdout(), 
    text = "
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, error = TRUE)

# override error output hook here
knitr::knit_hooks$set(error = function(x, options) {
  ERROR <<- x
  knitr::knit_exit()
})
knitr::knit_hooks$set(chunk = function(x, options){
  if(exists('ERROR')) paste0(x,'```\n',ERROR,'```\n\n**Skript stopped with error**')
  else x
})
```

```{r}
1 + 1
```

```{r}
stop('Test')
``` 

This text should not be in the output.

```{r}
2 + 2
```
")
````